# Mysqli Select based on date with an OR condition

Tags: mysql

Looking to pull data from a database based on one anchor condition, in this case, a date, and then looking at four other rows for conditional data.

```
SELECT id FROM Schedule WHERE center = '96' OR ar1 = '96' OR ar2 = '96' OR 4th = '96' OR mentor = '96' AND date = '2022-09-03' AND kickoff <= '17:45' AND kickoff >= '18:55'
```

In this case, I'm looking for any database column that has 96 as an entry where the date is 2022-09-03, and the kickoff is between 17:45 and 18:55

My issue is that on another date, 96 is entered in the AR1 column, but the SELECT is returning as if 96 has an entry for the 2022-09-03 date.

I have also tried the following.

```
SELECT id FROM Schedule WHERE (center = '96' OR ar1 = '96' OR ar2 = '96' OR 4th = '96' OR mentor = '96') AND (date = '2022-09-03' AND kickoff <= '17:45' AND kickoff >= '18:55');
```

The date that has data of 96 is 2022-09-11, but the queries that target 2022-09-03 are returning 2022-09-11 as a result.

Comment: I think you have your alligator mouths eating the wrong side. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a1eb7/4

Comment: For the kickoff section of the query, I sure did!

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.  I got it.

SELECT id FROM Schedule WHERE date = '2022-09-03' AND kickoff >= '17:45:00' AND kickoff <= '18:55:00' AND (center = '96' OR ar1 = '96' OR ar2 = '96' OR 4th = '96' OR mentor = '96');

returns nothing as expected.

SELECT id FROM Schedule WHERE date = '2022-09-11' AND kickoff >= '17:45:00' AND kickoff <= '18:55:00' AND (center = '96' OR ar1 = '96' OR ar2 = '96' OR 4th = '96' OR mentor = '96');

returns the data as expected.